# MatPlotLib + GeoPandas: Plot Multiple Layers, Control Figsize

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, figure, geopandas

Given the shape file available [here](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2015/shp/cb_2015_us_county_20m.zip): I know can produce the basic map that I need with county labels and even some points on the map (see below). The issue I'm having is that I cannot seem to control the size of the figure with figsize. 
Here's what I have:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
figsize=5,5
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(figsize),dpi=300)

shpfileshpfile=r'Y:\HQ\TH\Groups\NR\PSPD\Input\US_Counties\cb_2015_us_county_20m.shp' 
c=gpd.read_file(shpfile)
c=c.loc[c['GEOID'].isin(['26161','26093','26049','26091','26075','26125','26163','26099','26115','26065'])]
c['coords'] = c['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.representative_point().coords[:])
c['coords'] = [coords[0] for coords in c['coords']]
ax=c.plot()

#Control some attributes regarding the axis (for the plot above)   

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False);ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False);ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False);ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',left='off',right='off',color='none',labelcolor='none')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',top='off',bottom='off',color='none',labelcolor='none')
    for idx, row in c.iterrows():
        ax.annotate(s=row['NAME'], xy=row['coords'],
                     horizontalalignment='center')
lat2=[42.5,42.3]
lon2=[-84,-83.5]

   #Add another plot...

ax.plot(lon2,lat2,alpha=1,marker='o',linestyle='none',markeredgecolor='none',markersize=15,color='white')
plt.show()
```

As you can see, I opted to call the plots by the axis name because I need to control attributes of the axis, such as tick_params. I'm not sure if there is a better approach. This seems like a "no-brainer" but I can't seem to figure out why I can't control the figure size.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do the following:

1. Use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (figsize))`

2.use the ax=ax argument in c.plot()

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
figsize=5,5
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(figsize),dpi=300)
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (figsize))
shpfileshpfile=r'Y:\HQ\TH\Groups\NR\PSPD\Input\US_Counties\cb_2015_us_county_20m.shp' 
c=gpd.read_file(shpfile)
c=c.loc[c['GEOID'].isin(['26161','26093','26049','26091','26075','26125','26163','26099','26115','26065'])]
c['coords'] = c['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.representative_point().coords[:])
c['coords'] = [coords[0] for coords in c['coords']]
c.plot(ax=ax)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False);ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False);ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False);ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',left='off',right='off',color='none',labelcolor='none')
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',top='off',bottom='off',color='none',labelcolor='none')
for idx, row in c.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(s=row['NAME'], xy=row['coords'],
                 horizontalalignment='center')
lat2=[42.5,42.3]
lon2=[-84,-83.5]
ax.plot(lon2,lat2,alpha=1,marker='o',linestyle='none',markeredgecolor='none',markersize=15,color='white')
```